# How to enter a string to an array to a given position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The condition is such that I have to enter a string to an array to a given position
such that all the pre position if not exist should be made to be empty strings.

example;

```
var array = []; // now I want to enter a string 'hello' at index 2
```

now the array should look like:

```
array = [ '','','hello']; //now lets say I want to enter a string 'world' at index 4
```

so the array should become:

```
array = [ '','','hello','','world'];
```

Is there a way to do this?
or do i have a better option to enter a string and and its position?

Please enlighten me.. :)

Comment: It seems to be a weird requirement. Do you mind explaining how you would use this? There's possibly better ways of achieving your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. The function takes three arguments: the target array, the index (0-based) and the value. Just iterate from the finish of you array to the new position and add `""` to each entry, then, after the loop, enqueue the desired string. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLjvh4k7/).

```js
let a = ['', '', 'Hello'];

function addStringAtPosition(
  array,
  key,
  value
) {
  for (let i = array.length; i < key; i++) {
    array[i] = '';
  }

  array[key] = value;
}

addStringAtPosition(a, 5, 'World!');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First find out how many additional elements need to add ''
2. push these new elements to array.
3. push the required value at end.

PS: Assumed the index always higher than the array length. We can add conditions to cover those cases as well.

```js
const insert = (arr, value, index) => {
  arr.push(...new Array(index - arr.length).fill(""));
  arr.push(value);
  return arr;
};

const array = [];

insert(array, "hello", 2);
console.log(array);
insert(array, "world", 4);
console.log(array);
```